# Change remote directory ownership without ssh

Tags: apache, security, ssh, phpmyadmin, vps

First, I feel very silly.

For fun/slight profit, I rent a vps which hosts an email and web server and which I use largely as a study aid.  Recently, I was in the middle of working on something, and managed to lose connection to the box directly after having accidentally changed the ownership of my home folder to an arbitrary non-root, incorrect user.  As ssh denies root, and anything but pubkey authentication, I'm in a bad way.  Though the machine is up, I can't access it!

Assuming this is the only issue, a single chown should fix the problem, but I haven't been able to convince my provider's support team to do this.

So my question is this: have I officially goofed, or is there some novel way I can fix my setup?

I have all the passwords and reasonable knowledge of how all the following public facing services are configured:

- Roundcube mail
- Dovecot and postfix running imaps, smtps and smtp
- Apache (but my websites are all located in that same home folder, and
  so aren't accessible - At least I now get why this was a very bad idea...)
- Baikal calendar setup in a very basic fashion
- phpMyAdmin but with MySql's file creation locked to a folder which apache isn't serving

I've investigated some very simple ways to 'abuse' some of the other services in a way that might allow me either shell access, or some kind of chown primitive, but this isn't really my area.

Thanks!!

Comment: do you have ftp access to your box?

Comment: @Lelio Unfortunately not

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question does not seem to be about programming nor about some tool needed for programming. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question could be more appropriate on one of the many stackexchange sites, may be serverfault.com

Comment: serverfault makes more sense i suppose...

Comment: I had a similar problem to this, and the only way I managed to get access to is by asking my service provider to put the VPS to recovery mode and login through web console and make necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

None of these will help you, at least of the services you listed none have the ability to restore the permissions.

All the VPS providers I've used give "console" access through the web interface. This is equivalent to sitting down at the machine, including the ability to login or reboot in recovery mode. Your hosting provider probably offers some similar functionality (for situations just like this, or for installing the operating system, etc), and it is going to be your easiest and most effective means of recovery. Log in there as root and restore your user's permissions.

One thing struck me as odd,

> I haven't been able to convince my provider's support team to do this.

Is that because they don't want to do anything on your server which you aren't paying them to manage, or because they don't understand what you're asking? The latter would be quite odd to me, but the former scenario would be very typical of an unmanaged VPS setup (you have root, console access, and anything more than that is your problem).